# Issues with Nuget 2.8.50126.477 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to add a package through Nuget 2.8.50126.477 in Visual Studio 2013 on my office laptop. But Nuget seems to be stuck retrieving information forever.

Note that I am able to use Nuget 1.2 with Visual Studio 2010 from the same laptop. My devenv.exe.config files for both versions of visual studio have the following entries:

```
<system.net>    
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy proxyaddress="http://MYPROXYHERE:8080" bypassonlocal="True"/>      
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

I even tried running VS in admin mode as someone suggested in another thread, but Nuget doesn't work still.

Answer (score 1):

Please report this issue on https://nuget.codeplex.com/ and provide as many details as you can. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I reported the issue on the Nuget Codeplex site on Mar 25. Here is the link- https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4093